# Macintosh HD - Data

Tags: macbook-pro

I am using the macOS Monterey System on my MacBook Pro. Upon restarting my machine a pop-up box appears wanting me to enter a password to unlock the "Macintosh HD-Data. I was able to go into security settings and open the FileVault and generate a recovery key but it won't take that as the password either.

Comment: Did you encrypt the disk when setting up the macOS or MacBook for the first time ?

Comment: We are not sure, we think we would but no ones 100%

Comment: Have you try desactivate Filevault then re-enable it?